# Remove a dataframe in a nested list and add another dataframe in same nested list in R

Tags: r

I want to remove the "$ plink_fam:'data.frame" from a nested list called "format_files" in list (genotypes) and add another dataframe called "df" in same nested list "format files".
how can I do it ?

code

```
glimpse(genotypes)
```

output

```
List of 2
 $ id_snps     : chr [1:45807] "BovineHD0100000015" "Hapmap43437-BTA-101873" "BovineHD0100000062" "ARS-BFGL-NGS-16466" ...
 $ format_files:List of 2
  ..$ plink_fam:'data.frame':   38996 obs. of  6 variables:
  .. ..$ pedigree: logi [1:38996] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ member  : int [1:38996] 407243954 407537778 408990264 409742750 409817894 409859435 409922125 410570238 410829671 411075330 ...
  .. ..$ father  : int [1:38996] 400004752 400005622 412300604 412300604 400005917 400005850 400005850 400005375 400005607 400005356 ...
  .. ..$ mother  : int [1:38996] 406249617 406901234 411694156 408626860 410533913 411102034 411657369 407288999 408611867 407723032 ...
  .. ..$ sex     : int [1:38996] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
  .. ..$ affected: logi [1:38996] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  ..$ plink_map:'data.frame':   45807 obs. of  6 variables:
  .. ..$ chromosome: int [1:45807] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
  .. ..$ snp.name  : chr [1:45807] "BovineHD0100000015" "Hapmap43437-BTA-101873" "BovineHD0100000062" "ARS-BFGL-NGS-16466" ...
  .. ..$ cM        : logi [1:45807] NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
  .. ..$ position  : int [1:45807] 36337 135098 206470 267940 347418 348331 393248 471078 516341 533815 ...
  .. ..$ allele.1  : chr [1:45807] "G" "G" "C" "T" ...
  .. ..$ allele.2  : chr [1:45807] "A" "A" "T" "C" ...
```

Comment: Maybe `format_files[[1]] <- df`.

Comment: thanks, but did not work.

Comment: If the dataframe you want to remove is part of a list, use `genotypes$format_files[[1]]`. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the new data.frame in place, with an index returned by `grep`, then change the list member name.

```
i <- grep("plink_fam", names(genotypes$format_files))
genotypes$format_files[[i]] <- cars
names(genotypes$format_files)[i] <- "df"

str(genotypes)
#List of 2
# $ id_snps     : int [1:10] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
# $ format_files:List of 2
#  ..$ df       :'data.frame':  50 obs. of  2 variables:
#  .. ..$ speed: num [1:50] 4 4 7 7 8 9 10 10 10 11 ...
#  .. ..$ dist : num [1:50] 2 10 4 22 16 10 18 26 34 17 ...
#  ..$ plink_map:'data.frame':  32 obs. of  11 variables:
#  .. ..$ mpg : num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
#  .. ..$ cyl : num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
#  .. ..$ disp: num [1:32] 160 160 108 258 360 ...
#  .. ..$ hp  : num [1:32] 110 110 93 110 175 105 245 62 95 123 ...
#  .. ..$ drat: num [1:32] 3.9 3.9 3.85 3.08 3.15 2.76 3.21 3.69 3.92 3.92 ...
#  .. ..$ wt  : num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
#  .. ..$ qsec: num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
#  .. ..$ vs  : num [1:32] 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 ...
#  .. ..$ am  : num [1:32] 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  .. ..$ gear: num [1:32] 4 4 4 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 ...
#  .. ..$ carb: num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
```

**Test data**

```
genotypes <- list(
  id_snps = 1:10,
  format_files = list(
    plink_fam = iris, 
    plink_map = mtcars
  )
)
```

Comment: thank youuuu, it worked. what should I do  if I want to add a dataframe in  list (genotype)?  not in nested list (format_files).